# Firebase Event Listener failing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to make a Firebase event listener as part of my class but its failing and I'm not sure why.

```
class User: NSObject {

let userRef = Firebase(url:"https://karmadots.firebaseio.com/karmadots/users")
let standbyRef = Firebase(url:"https://karmadots.firebaseio.com/karmadots/standby")

var firstName = ""
var lastName = ""
var userDescription = ""
var email = ""
var userID = ""
var eventHostedID = ""
var invitedToEvent:[String] = []

// Set up own user
func setupUser(){
    var id:String = self.userRef.authData.uid
    println(id)  // Prints "Simplelogin:3"

    # FAILS HERE
    self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(id).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value,withBlock: {snapshot in

       # DOESNT GET TO BREAKPOINT HERE

        println(snapshot.value)

        self.firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"] as String
        self.lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"] as String
        self.userDescription = snapshot.value["description"] as String
        self.email = snapshot.value["email"] as String
        self.eventHostedID = snapshot.value["eventHosted"] as String
        self.userID = self.userRef.authData.uid

    })
}
}
```

I make the call as part of my code as such:

```
self.userRef.observeAuthEventWithBlock({ authData in
    if authData != nil {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        println(authData)
        self.user.setupUser()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Authenticate User", sender: nil)
    } else {
        // No user is logged in
    }
})
```

Output is:

```
AuthData simplelogin:3
simplelogin:3
```

Is there something with doing a firebase query thats making it fail? I get a "EXC_BREAKPOINT (Code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)" and then a bunch of other crazy stuff looking like this:

```
0x10547489c:  jne    0x105474890               ;      swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x10547489e:  leaq   0x36b7d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x1054748a5:  movq   %rax, 0xb4c0c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x1054748ac:  int3   
0x1054748ad:  movq   %rdi, %rax
```

Comment: Clarification: there is [query](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) here. Just an [event listener](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-once).

Comment: Most likely, self.userRef.authData is nil. I'm guessing it's actually failing there and that the println(id) is not working as well as you've suggested here. It probably produces different results on multiple calls.

Comment: @Kato the print statement outputs "Simplelogin:3" everytime so I'm not sure whats wrong. What do you mean by produces different results?

Comment: Try wrapping your call to setupUser() in a call to [observeAuthEventWithBlock() as described here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication). Make sure the user data is not nil. There are no guarantees that self.userRef.authData actually exists.

Comment: @Kato That didn't work. Updated the post with call and output.

Comment: @jshah  Try to force unwrap uid! . Most likey the value you get is Optional(uid value)